# initialization increment decrement And and or operators

Tags: c++, c

Can any one explain this statement

```
int x=1,y=11,z;
z=x--&&y++¦¦--x;
```

I know the answer but not able to think that how it is coming

Comment: Break it down into pieces according to order of operations and process each piece separately, then assemble. [Mind the sequencing guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) from the `&&` and `||`

Comment: I believe that use of `x--` and `--x` in the same statement is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: @daShier normally it is. I'm much more familiar with C++, but I can't imagine [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) conditional logic would work in C without C having similar sequencing rules (WRT conditional operators. Outside that all bets are off) to C++.

Comment: What is the answer you know?

Comment: @user4581301 there is indeed a sequence point between the subexpressions of `&&` and `||` operators (and all other operators that short-circuit). So you are right, this is indeed a well formed expression.

Comment: @user4581301 reference here just in case - `C11`, chapter [§Cp1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Cp1)

Comment: Thanks, @AjayBrahmakshatriya . I looked it up [here in a more human-friendly format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order). Good to see the official text though.

Comment: This would be an non maintainable piece of code. It may have value as a puzzle, but otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty simple

```
x--
```

returns 1 (true). Therefore

```
y++
```

is evaluated. It returns 11

```
1 && 11
```

returns true. Since

```
true || X
```

is always true

```
--x
```

is not evaluated. The statement returns true (1).

This is called short-circuit evaluation. E.g.

```
a && b || c
```

means

```
if a is true
    evaluate b 
if a && b is false
    evaluate c
```

You could rewrite it as

```
int x=1,y=11,z;
z=[&]() {
    if (!(x--)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (y++) {
        return true;
    }
    if (x++) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}();
```

It's important to notice that the order of evaluation is as described. That's one of the reasons you shouldn't overload operator&& or operator||. The described behavior only works if the operators are not overloaded.